# Oltu compilation

Tags: maven, oltu

I tried to compile Oltu source I cloned from

https://github.com/apache/oltu.git

I could not get the project packaged with `mvn package -DskipTests` nor `mvn compile package -DskipTests` because it was interrupted by an error at **Apache Oltu - Demos - Client**,

```
[ERROR] /dev/oltu/demos/client-demo/src/main/java/o$
g/apache/oltu/oauth2/client/demo/controller/TokenController.java:[45,53] packag$
 org.apache.oltu.openidconnect.client.response does not exist
[ERROR] /dev/oltu/demos/client-demo/src/main/java/o$
g/apache/oltu/oauth2/client/demo/controller/TokenController.java:[91,22] cannot 
find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class OpenIdConnectResponse
[ERROR] location: class org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.demo.controller.TokenCont$
oller
[ERROR] /dev/oltu/demos/client-demo/src/main/java/o$
g/apache/oltu/oauth2/client/demo/controller/TokenController.java:[102,17] canno$
 find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class OpenIdConnectResponse
[ERROR] location: class org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.demo.controller.TokenCont$
oller
[ERROR] /dev/oltu/demos/client-demo/src/main/java/o$
g/apache/oltu/oauth2/client/demo/controller/TokenController.java:[102,65] canno$
 find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class OpenIdConnectResponse
[ERROR] location: class org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.demo.controller.TokenCont$
oller
```

However, I could get it to compile if I have 2 explicit steps i.e.

1. `mvn compile`
2. `mvn package -DskipTests`

My questions is, is it not `mvn package` includes `compile`? Why does it package the project when I run it explicitly? Thanks